# How to disable few check boxes in a CheckBoxList in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am using CHtml::checkBoxList in my Yii application. I need to disable few checkboxes based on some criteria. How can I do that using Yii itself?

Below is my code

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('sid','',$posts1, array('id'=>'1','template' => '{input}{label}</td></tr><tr><td width="10%" style="padding:0 0 10px 20px;" class="rbr">','checkAll' => 'All'));
```

This will generate a table similar to the image below

[image]

What I need is to disable the checkbox corresponding to the first row. i.e., the check box with 4X-B in its row.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Want To know whether you are using CGridView or Your Custom Table

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible using CHtml class. You can create `custom Html class`. Or use `foreach` to generate html.

Answer (score 0):

create an Action as

```
 public function actionIndex() {

    $model= new CActiveDataProvider('ModelClass');

    $this->render('index',array('model' => $model));

}
```

In Index.php view file

```
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'disabled' => '$data->last_column=="4X-B" ? true : false',
    ),
    'country',
    'last_column'
)
));
?>
```

Read [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

Comment: `disabled` is not an attribute of CCheckBoxColumn.

Comment: disabled is a public property with php expression of CCheckBoxColumn you read it in CCheckBoxColumn API.